# Facebook, posting photos to user's profile offline (permissions)

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, permissions

According to the Facebook documentation, if we have `publish_stream` permission, we should be able to post content without requiring the `offline_access` permission. Does this apply to posting photos to a user's photo library?

In our Canvas app, we store the user's oauth token and are able to post to the user's wall with no problem. However, when we try to post photos to that user (using a `POST` to `/user id/photos`) it *usually* works. When it fails we get:

```
{"error":
    {"message":"A user access token is required to request this resource.",
     "type":"OAuthException"
    }
}
```

TLDR: Are we wrong in thinking that publish_stream covers posting to user's photo library offline despite Facebook's documentation?

Comment: Are you making the post with an access_token /user_id/photos?access_token=alsdkja;ldfjlksdjfaksdjflksfjlkdj

Comment: Yeah. $facebook->api('/' . $row["fb_user_id"] . '/photos?access_token=' . $row["oauth_access_token"], 'POST', array( ... ) );  // $row is from our database.

Comment: how are you generating the access token before added to database. 
 you can debug them in the token debuger! https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug  just paste the token in, should show any errors if any.

Comment: from the blog sample at https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/498/ you can add photos to exsisting albums or create an album with photos, with only publish_stream

Comment: Thanks for the replies! Unfortunately, the blog post example is using tokens available as the user is interacting with the app, which doesn't work if the user logs out or 1-2 hours pass. Basically they create an image with our app which goes into a moderation queue. If the user logs out of Facebook or 1-2 hours have passed between them creating the image and us approving the image, the token is no longer usable for posting the image to the user's library.

Comment: if you detect the user token is expired, you should be able request an app access_token and post as user to user profile.  https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/album/

if i am reading docs correctly it is any valid access_token, but should use user token where avail.

Comment: Unfortunately, that's the problem. App tokens don't work for posting photos to a user's library. It works great for posting to their streams, but not photos. Need a 'User' access_token, apparently, but can't find a way to get a new one if the one we pulled when the user was on the app expires.

Comment: "OOOOPS!" Something went wrong you need to re-upload your pics again for the 3rd time we are sorry about this.

https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/576/

The only solution that i can see it let them upload right away with out approval then have admins delete what is unwanted from log.  This will probably not work in your case, so offline access seems to be the only solution.

Comment: That's the conclusion we eventually arrived at, unfortunately this conclusion came at the cost of a lot of wasted time. Wish Facebook was a little clearer on what 'content' implies when they say you don't need offline_access to post it.